# Set font background color to transparent on desktop

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, fonts

I've already done this:

```
Control Panel / System / Advanced / Performance Tab / 
Settings Button and put a checkmark in: Use Drop Shadows for Icon Labels on
```

But I still get a color in the font background. There's no "transparent" option in *Properties/Desktop* and there's always a color set here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick Google revealed that even with the 'Use Drop Shadows for Icon Labels' option enabled you need to check the following:

- Right-click on Desktop -> Arrange Icons by -> Lock Web items on Desktop must be cleared.
- If you have any web content on your desktop, transparency won't work. To check for web content: Right-click on Desktop -> Properties -> Desktop -> Customize Desktop -> Web and make sure all checkboxes are clear.
- Your wallpaper must be an image file (.jpg, .bmp etc.) not an HTML document (.html / .htm)

Comment: Side note: If it still doesn't work, your picture is likely a png file. I have faced this problem right now, and it worked after converting the picture to a jpg file.